# A pointer in the right direction

Tags: web-services, macos, sqlite, parsing, ios

I have been developing a Mac Desktop app with an iOS device counterpart.
Basically I want to upload event information (music gigs etc.) from the Desktop to an online database and be able to read (only)  the information whilst mobile.

I've got both apps working, using Core Data (with a sqlite database - I was going to use XML but the iOS doesn't seem to let me do that), but I'm at a loss when it comes to the Web Services part.

I've been googling and checking docs involving sqlite, XML, JSON, `NSXMLParser` (do I need restful services?)and umpteen other things and I'm just getting nowhere fast.

Could someone explain to me the principle involved?  Do I actually need Core Data?  Do I have to convert the sqlite data to XML and back again to read it via an iOS mobile device?

I feel I'm making this out to be way more complicated than it should be - or is it?

Hoping someone can put me straight.  Hope I've given enough information.

Comment: Ok, so I've been thinking about it and I reckon the way forward is to change the Core Data store file on my desktop to XML, upload the file to the server then parse it with NSXMLParser, like in SeismicXML.  I'll then assign the parsed content to invoked objects on the mobile device, where it'll be stored locally using Core Data.  I think I'm making progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i do, and I have done many web service iOS apps. I make a webpage in JSON, call it, and then I use `SBJsonParser`, which parses the JSON into native objects, like a dictionary or array of dictionaries, then I display the data. It really is very simple.

The at a specific time like `ViewDidLoad`, I fetch the JSON file. Remember, the json document can be web service or just a text file. Whatever you need. JSON doesn't need extra code, is extremely `lightweight`, and parses without any interference into native objects. Less work for you.